# Problema com stream de áudio no android

Tags: android, stream

O meu código resumido é esse:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://stm43.srvstm.com:8474/;");

mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });

mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                mp.reset();
                Log.i("informacao", "erro "+ what + " -- " + extra);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

O logcat está me retornando a seguinte mensagem:

> ? I/informacao: erro 1 -- -2147483648

Segundo a documentação do MediaPLayer o erro de numeração 1 é o MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN
que é descrito como "Unspecified media player error.", o teste que apresentou esse erro foi feito em um emulador com o android 8.1 (Oreo), nas versões 4.4.2 e 6.0 funciona normalmente, gostaria de entender o motivo de não funcionar na versão 8.1 e quais são as alternativas para fazer com que esse stream funcione nas versões mais recentes do android.

Se o link for acessado dessa forma http://stm43.srvstm.com:8474/listen.pls em um navegador, um arquivo é baixado e ao abrir o arquivo .pls o stream funciona no computador normalmente.

Informação sobre o stream:
(HE-AAC @ 64 kbps, 44.1 kHz)

Comment: Testei no android 8.1 e ele funciona. A única coisa que alterava no código é passar `mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();` para depois de `setOnPreparedListener()`.

Comment: Como assim? acabei de testar outra vez e as mensagem de erro é a mesma, você utilizou outros recursos? ou somente uma Activity com esse código?

Comment: Apenas uma Activity com esse código

Comment: Ok, ainda continuo sem entender, mas vou fazer novos testes em outros emuladores e outras versões, mais tarde atualizo aqui os resultados.

Comment: @ramaral eu criei um novo projeto do zero como você fez e testei, funcionou normalmente. Ai achei estranho já que estava tentando e buscando uma solução a algum tempo, depois de alguns dia tentando entender, percebi que o erro não estava nesse código e sim em outra parte do projeto, Como eu posso proceder nesse cenário? Eu edito a pergunta informando o problema e como resolvi, crio uma resposta ou respondo aqui mesmo nos comentários ?

Comment: Se a razão do problema tem relação com o MediaPlayer e é algo que pode acontecer com outros, deve responder. No entanto, não tem mal nenhum colocar uma resposta, mesmo que as circunstâncias sejam outras.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema foi gerado devido a uma falta de atenção, fiquei pensando que o problema estava nesse código e esqueci do contexto o qual ele estava inserido. Eu percebi que no meu projeto foi implementado a configuração de segurança da rede e que nesse meu cenário acabou "atrapalhando" o MediaPlayer desempenhar a sua função, conseguir perceber isso após testar a codificação em um projeto sem configuração nenhuma, iniciado do zero.

No meu AndroidManifest.xml eu tinha o seguinte:

```
...
 <application
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
...
```

e no meu network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">stm43.srvstm.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

A documentação explica que essa configuração que eu utilizei serve para garantir que todas as conexões com secure.example.com (no meu caso stm43.srvstm.com) sejam sempre realizadas por HTTPS para proteger o tráfego confidencial de redes hostis.
Buscando entender um pouco mais, dentro da explicação do método:

```
NetworkSecurityPolicy.isCleartextTrafficPermitted()
```

Eu encontrei o seguinte, "Quando o tráfego de rede de texto não criptografado não é permitido, os componentes da plataforma (por exemplo, pilhas HTTP e FTP DownloadManager, **MediaPlayer**) recusarão as solicitações deste processo para usar o tráfego de texto não criptografado. Bibliotecas de terceiros são fortemente encorajadas a honrar essa configuração também." Por isso alguns players que testei não funcionaram também.

E o motivo do app só está funcionando com versões inferiores ao android 6.0 (API 23), é que estes "confiam no repositório de CAs adicionadas pelo usuário por padrão", já nas versões superiores o android estava levando em consideração a minha configuração de segurança da rede (network_security_config.xml).

**Fontes:**

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config?hl=pt-br

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/NetworkSecurityPolicy.html?hl=pt-br#isCleartextTrafficPermitted()

Answer (score -1):

Opa, tudo bem!?

Já ouviu falar no ExoPlayer? se não, de uma olhada. Uma ferramenta fantástica e muito simples de implementar.

Reproduzir vídeos e músicas é uma atividade popular em dispositivos Android. O framework Android fornece MediaPlayer, uma solução rápida para reproduzir mídia com código mínimo. Ele também fornece APIs de mídia de baixo nível, como MediaCodec, AudioTracke MediaDrm, que podem ser usadas para criar soluções personalizadas de media player.

O ExoPlayer é um reprodutor de mídia de nível aberto e nível de aplicativo construído sobre as APIs de mídia de baixo nível do Android. Este guia descreve a biblioteca do ExoPlayer e seu uso. Refere-se ao código no aplicativo de demonstração principal do ExoPlayer para fornecer exemplos concretos. O guia aborda os prós e contras do uso do ExoPlayer. Ele mostra como usar o ExoPlayer para reproduzir fluxos adaptáveis ​​DASH, SmoothStreaming e HLS, bem como formatos como MP4, M4A, FMP4, WebM, MKV, MP3, Ogg, WAV, MPEG-TS, MPEG-PS, FLV e ADTS ( AAC). Ele também discute eventos, mensagens, personalização e suporte a DRM do ExoPlayer.

Saiba mais em: https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/

Caso tenha dúvidas na implementação podemos lhe ajudar, mas é muito simples e fácil. Está tudo detalhado na documentação.
Confira alguns exemplos: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/demos

Comment: O conteúdo até pode ser útil, mas não responde à pergunta.

Comment: muitas vezes pode ser mais viável implementar uma ferramenta assim, do que ficar martelando no problemas. Não vejo problema nela, pois suporta o que ele necessita, tem suporte a API 19 pra cima, e é de fácil implementacao, nao custa nada fazer um teste e ver se enquadra e resolve o problema dele.

Comment: A questão que levanto é que a resposta não responde há pergunta. O ExoPlayer apenas é uma alternativa. Por que não sugerir que deixe de usar Android e passe a usar ios? :)

Comment: Até porque o código apresentado funciona no Android 8.1.

Comment: @LeonardoFigueiredo Obrigado pela tentativa, porém como já foi dito não responde a pergunta, até por que eu já havia testando com alguns outros players e estava tendo o mesmo problema, nunca tocava, eu estava pensando que era algum problema de compatibilidade com o stream e então tentei diversos outros players e sempre sem sucesso. Eu já encontrei o problema, daqui a pouco vou colocar aqui o motivo.